# Remove only the trailing elements of a Vec that match a condition

Tags: iterator, rust

I have a `Vec<T>` that has elements matching a pattern. I want to remove all trailing instances of the elements that match the pattern.

For example, I have a `Vec<i32>` and the pattern is `(|x| x == 0)`. If the input was: `vec![0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0]`, the output should be: `vec![0, 1, 0, 2, 3]`

To do this I tried:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0];
    vec = vec.into_iter().rev().skip_while(|&x| x == 0).rev();
}
```

But I get these compiler errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::iter::SkipWhile<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>, [closure@src/main.rs:3:44: 3:55]>: std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:57
  |
3 |     vec = vec.into_iter().rev().skip_while(|&x| x == 0).rev();
  |                                                         ^^^ the trait `std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator` is not implemented for `std::iter::SkipWhile<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>, [closure@src/main.rs:3:44: 3:55]>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:11
  |
3 |     vec = vec.into_iter().rev().skip_while(|&x| x == 0).rev();
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found struct `std::iter::Rev`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>`
             found type `std::iter::Rev<std::iter::SkipWhile<std::iter::Rev<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>>, [closure@src/main.rs:3:44: 3:55]>>`
```

The strange thing is that `DoubleEndedIterator` is implemented for `SkipWhile`. In fact, `SkipWhile` even implements `rev()`. [See here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.SkipWhile.html).

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error messages state:

1. *the trait `DoubleEndedIterator` is not implemented for `SkipWhile<...>`* — Take a look at the implementation of `SkipWhile`:

   ```
   pub struct SkipWhile<I, P> {
       iter: I,
       flag: bool,
       predicate: P,
   }
   ```

   You cannot reverse an iterator built from `SkipWhile` because it has no way of tracking if the "current" item was skipped when you add in the ability to pull from the front and the back.
2. *expected struct `Vec`, found struct `Rev`* — You still have an iterator, but you are trying to store it where a `Vec` must be stored. You cannot put a type A where a type B is needed.

I would [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) the vector and then [`reverse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.reverse) it in place:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0];

    vec = vec.into_iter().rev().skip_while(|&x| x == 0).collect();
    vec.reverse();

    println!("{:?}", vec);
    assert_eq!(vec, [0, 1, 0, 2, 3]);
}
```

---

> `DoubleEndedIterator` is implemented for `SkipWhile`.

This is not true. If you look at the documentation for [`SkipWhile`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.SkipWhile.html), it does not list that it implements `DoubleEndedIterator`. Here's an example of a trait it does implement: [`FusedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.SkipWhile.html#impl-FusedIterator).

> In fact, `SkipWhile` even implements `rev()`

It doesn't actually. `Iterator::rev` is only implemented in the condition that `Self` (which is `SkipWhile`) implements `DoubleEndedIterator`, which this doesn't:

```
fn rev(self) -> Rev<Self>
where
    Self: DoubleEndedIterator,
```

Answer (score 7):

The iterator adaptor for reversal only works for iterators which can be traversed from any of the two ends (as in, it is a [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html)). While this is the case for the original one, this is no longer possible from the moment we include `skip_while`. In order to follow that approach, you would have to collect the rest of the reversed vector, and only then reverse again.

I, on the other hand, would just choose to fetch the index of the first trailing zero and truncate the vector with it.

```
let mut vec = vec![0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0];
if let Some(i) = vec.iter().rposition(|x| *x != 0) {
    let new_len = i + 1;
    vec.truncate(new_len);
}
```

... or just grab a slice instead:

```
let piece = &vec[..new_len];
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a8f1e9e4f57da0d06ed787c9c74be821&version=stable)

Comment: I like this solution as it's probably the most memory-efficient of the answers. If you wanted to keep the `take_while`, you could use `.take_while(|&&x| x == 0).count()`.

Comment: You can express your intent more clearly by using [rposition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rposition).

Comment: @raggy Thanks, that tweak was added now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to get things started, here is a really dodgy solution:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0];
    vec = vec.into_iter().rev().skip_while(|&x| x == 0).collect();
    vec = vec.into_iter().rev().collect();
}
```